# About isomorphism of rings and fields

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

If $A,B$ are rings and $A$ is a field. If $A$ is a field and $A\cong B$ so $B$ is a field too?

Thank you!

Comment: They're isomorphic. That means they're basically the same thing.

Comment: @anon I don't think that's particularly helpful... for instance, if $A,B$ are isomorphic as groups and $A$ is a ring, it does *not* follow that $B$ is a ring.

Comment: @user7530, yes it does.  One can define a ring structure on B in the obvious way, where multiplication is given by multiplying the corresponding elements of A (and then going back to B); the axioms follow directly from the ring axioms of A.  Anyway, being a field is a _property_ (of a ring) while being a ring is an additional _structure_ (on a group).

Comment: By the way, another way to see this is to recall that fields are characterized as rings with only trivial ideals, and note that ideals are stable under isomorphism.

Comment: @Adeel Yes, that is true, and it's a good insight. I guess my point is that an isomorphism of groups/rings/what have you implies a map that preserves a very specific amount of structure only, and that thinking of an isomorphism between two objects as meaning they are "basically the same thing" is not nuanced enough to be helpful. That being a field is a property of rings, rather than additional structure, and thus preserved by ring isomorphisms is true, but perhaps not obvious (and is the point of the problem, after all).

Comment: @user7530, yes, what anon said is certainly insufficient.

Comment: What anon said is exactly how one should think about these statements. But of course one should have some mathematical maturity in order to understand this properly, and asking such a trivial question (where one doesn't need any ideas to solve it) shows that one isn't prepared for this yet.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\phi: A \leftrightarrow B$ is a ring isomorphism. $B$ is a field if it is commutative, and if every non-zero element of $B$ has a multiplicative inverse.

Let $a,b$ be two elements of $B$. Then
$$ab = \phi\left(\phi^{-1}(a)\right)\phi\left(\phi^{-1}(b)\right) = \phi\left(\phi^{-1}(a)\phi^{-1}(b)\right) = \ldots$$
can you finish the argument?

Similarly, let $b$ be a nonzero element of $B$. Can you prove $\phi^{-1}(b)$ is nonzero? How might you use $\phi^{-1}(b)$ to construct the multiplicative inverse of $b$?

Comment: I think yes, I need to try...

Comment: Fields are also required to be nonzero.

Answer (score 3):

To check that $B$ is a field, we must check that the field axioms hold for $B$. That is, $B$ is a commutative ring such that every non-zero element of $B$ is a unit. If $A \cong B$ as rings, then clearly $B$ is a commutative ring if and only if $A$ is. $A$ is commutative as it's a field, hence $B$ is also. Now for the second part. Let $b \in B, b \neq 0$. Let $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ be a ring isomorphism. There is $a \in A, a \neq 0$ such that $\phi(a)=b$. As $A$ is a field, there is $a' \in A$ such that $aa'=a'a=1_A$ in $A$. Let $b'=\phi(a')$. So $1_B=\phi(1_A)=\phi(aa')=\phi(a)\phi(a')=bb'=b'b$, so $b$ is a unit in $B$. QED

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If a polynomial has a root in a ring, then it has a root in every image of the ring. Applying this to $\, ax - 1$ we deduce that images of units remain units.

**Remark** $ $ I elaborate, since the hint appears to be too concise for at least one reader.  In order not to completely spoil the hint I consider an analogous example. Consider the class of rings that are *root-closed*, i.e. every element has a square-root in the ring. I claim that this property is *preserved*  in every ring image $\,h(R)\,$ of a root-closed ring $\,R.$ Indeed, an element of $\,h(R)\,$ has form $\,h(a).\,$ But $\,a = x^2$ for some $\,x\in R.$ Its image $\,h(a) = h(x^2)=(h(x))^2$ shows that $\,h(x)\,$ remains a root of $\,h(a)\,$ in $\,h(R).\,$ So, as claimed, $\,h(R)\,$ is root-closed too.

Similarly, any "root existence" property will be preserved in ring-images, i.e. any property of the form $\,\forall a\,\exists x\!:\ f(a,x) = 0,\,$ for some polynomial $\,f.\,$ Fields are of this type, being those rings such that $\,ax = 1\,$ has a root, i.e. $\,\forall a\ne 0,\,\exists x\!:\ ax = 1.$

Model theory studies in much greater details the forms of statements that are preserved under homomorphisms, subalgebras, products, etc, as well as many other types of relationships between syntax and semantics in equational algebras.